# Problem installing Ruby on Rails server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ruby, pi-models

I tried using a Type A RP as a Rails server. Rails installs alright, but bundle install never manages to finish. I think it is due to too low RAM (256 on A model).

Does anyone have experience running Rails on a Model A?

I'll try it next on a Model B and see how that goes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure it didn't finish, it is likely to be very slow?

Comment: yes, very slow indeed..

Answer (score 1):

OK, Rails is running fine on a Model A RP once I excluded the production gems:

> bundle install --without production

Once I did that bundle finished and the rails app is running like a champ

Comment: Select this as a correct answer to mark the question closed.